# How do I access a random member of a Tuple?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I would like to access a random member of a tuple and I'm not sure how to set `#n` to a variable.

Here is my code:

```
val lis = ("a","b","c","d")
val randNumber = Random.randRange (1,4) (Random.rand (0,1)) 
val randChar = #randNumber lis //this is where its failing
```

This is how I would normally access, say member #2:

```
val lis = ("a","b","c","d")
val ranChar = #2 lis;
```

So my question is how do I set `#2` to a variable in the example above??

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: Why do you use a tuple when you want an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some workarounds, for example, you can explicitly match `randNumber` and call appropriate member functions:

```
    val randChar = case randNumber of
                      1 => #1 lis
                    | 2 => #2 lis
                    | 3 => #3 lis
                    | _ => #4 lis
```

Of course, this one doesn't scale very well. Another workaround is changing representation of `lis` to `List` and use `List.nth`:

```
List.nth(lis, randNumber-1)
```

Hope it helps you somehow.

Comment: I converted my Tuple to a list and used that function.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you cannot. What would be the type of the access operator?
If you want dynamic random access to your data, you should convert it into a vector first.

PS: there are languages (Coq, Agda, etc.) where such access operator can be typed, but that would require dependent types (or at least type-level integers plus some magic, maybe Omega can also do that).

Comment: Why, the type of such an accessor function would be (in Haskell notation: forall a b c d.(a,b,c,d) -> b. No magic there, it's an ordinary HM type scheme. See also fst and snd.

Comment: @Ingo, No, he's asking for something like `k:int -> (a_1, a_2..., a_N) -> a_k`.

Comment: @Ingo note that #1 and #2 already cannot be typed. `fst` and `snd` are only defined for 2-uples, but #1 works for any (non-empty) tuple.

Comment: Well I didn't realize that he'd ask for #k, he just notes #2. In that case you're of course right regarding the type.